# Cakephp post request to webservice

Tags: web-services, cakephp

I have a web service that works fine with get requests but trying to use post it doesn't seem to work. I have this in my routes:

```
Router::connect("/products/service_add", array("controller"=>"products", "action" => "service_add", 'seller'=>true, "[method]" => "POST"));
```

Seller is like an admin. I also have ParseExtensions('xml'). My action is:

```
    function seller_service_add() {
    $this->log("hit", 'debug');
    $hi = array("message"=>"hey");
    $this->set(compact('hi'));
}
```

and the view is:

```
<product>
  <?php echo $xml->serialize($hi); ?>
</product>
```

When I try to send a post to the API I just get a debug trace back with timer info. In the same script as I'm doing the post request I'm doing a get and when I run the script I can see the data passed by the API for the get but not for the post request.

The code I'm using to send the post is:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('Your' => 'Data');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/<project>/products/service_add.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);`
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working? Any help would be much appreciated.

Sorry if this is a bit verbose!

Update: I've added lines to spit stuff out to the cakephp debug log when actions are hit. I have one entry on the beforeFilter, this entry gets hit and I can see it in the log. The entry in the service_add action is not present in the log so I guess that the action is not being hit?

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

shouldn't this line be

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, I thought that it serialized the data? Either way I just tried it without the http_build_query and it still didn't work!